# ¿Cómo agrego un PictureBox que contiene un bitmap a un documento nuevo en pdf en Viusal Basic?

Tags: visual-studio, pdf

Estoy generando un código de barras en `Visual Basic` el código que genero, es de tipo `bitmap` y se guarda en un `PictureBox`, después doy clic en el botón guardar y me abre una ventana para elegir la ruta del archivo y el nombre del archivo pdf.

Al aceptar me sale el siguiente **error**:

> No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo ´System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' al tipo 'iTextSharp.text.IElement'

```
 Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
 Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
 Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
 Imports iTextSharp
 Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.Barcode39
 Imports System.IO
 Imports iTextSharp.text

 Public Class Form1
   Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tam As Integer
    tam = TxtCodigo.Text.Length()
    If (TxtCodigo.Text = "") Or (tam < 7) Then
        MsgBox("Ingresa un código a 7 digitos", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Else
        Dim bcode As New Barcode39
        bcode.StartStopText = True
        bcode.BarHeight = 50
        bcode.Code = TxtCodigo.Text
        Try
            Dim bm As New Bitmap(bcode.CreateDrawingImage(Color.Black, Color.White))
            img = New Bitmap(bm.Width, bm.Height + 14)
            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
            g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height + 14)

            Dim pintartexto As New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8)
            Dim brocha As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)

            Dim stringsize As New SizeF
            stringsize = g.MeasureString(TxtCodigo.Text, pintartexto)
            Dim centrox As Single = (bm.Width - stringsize.Width) / 2
            Dim x As Single = centrox
            Dim y As Single = bm.Height

            Dim drawformat As New StringFormat
            drawformat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
            g.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0)
            Dim ncode As String = TxtCodigo.Text.Substring(1, TxtCodigo.Text.Length - 2)
            g.DrawString(TxtCodigo.Text, pintartexto, brocha, x, y, drawformat)
            PictureBox1.Image = img
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("No se pudo generar el codigo de barras!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
    PictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height))
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    PrintPreviewDialog1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub TxtCodigo_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtCodigo.KeyPress
    If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = False
    ElseIf Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
        MsgBox("Solo se permiten numeros", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "pdf"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            Dim DOCUEMTO As New Document
            Dim ESCRITOR As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(DOCUEMTO, New FileStream(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create))
            DOCUEMTO.Open()
            DOCUEMTO.Add(PictureBox1)
            MsgBox("Creado el archivo")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: El error que me sale dice que "No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo ´System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox´ al tipo 'iTextSharp.text.IElement'"´.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade detalles relevantes como ese que acabas de mencionar, explicanos lo que pasa para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Estoy generando codigos de barra, los cuales guardo en un PictureBox, el programa funciona bien, si se crea el codigo de barra, y quiero que se guarde en un pdf y al momento de agregar el PictureBox al documento pdf(vacio) me aparece el error antes mencionada

Comment: espero que me puedan ayudar, soy nuevo en este foro, gracias

Comment: Vuelvo a pedirte de favor que edites la pregunta con el botón de Editar al pié de la pregunta, así llega a más desarrolladores tu pregunta.